# Space between columns in a tabular

Tags: tables, columns

I am trying to format the column space in a tabular. However by using Google I only found a global way to set every space the same (see code) with \tablecodesep.

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0em}
\noindent \begin{tabular}{@{}llllll}
    French      &       Native              & R     & R1        & R             & R2\\
    English     &       Fluent/Level C1     & Z     & Z1        & Z2            & Z3\\ 
    German      &       Level B2            & T1    & T2        & T3            & T4 \\
\end{tabular}
```

What I would like here is to set a space between column 1&2, 3&4, 5&6 and I different space between column 2&3, and 4&5.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: you have already shown the solution in your question:-) `@{}` removes the intercolumn space replacing it by whatever is between the braces. so nothing in your example but try `ll@{\hspace{1cm}}lll`

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot:):) ... sometimes it's too obvious

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`@{}` removes the intercolumn space replacing it by whatever is between the braces. So nothing in your example but try

```
 ll@{\hspace{1cm}}lll
```